# Plot R matrix columns according to column name

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot the following matrix `x`, so the *column data* are plotted according to their *column name* (i.e. `0.1`, `0.2`, etc.) on the x-axis.

```
> x
               0.1          0.2          0.3          0.4          0.5
 [1,] 5.000000e-01 5.000000e-01 5.000000e-01 5.000000e-01 0.5000000000
 [2,] 2.500000e-02 5.000000e-02 7.500000e-02 1.000000e-01 0.1250000000
 [3,] 2.437500e-03 9.500000e-03 2.081250e-02 3.600000e-02 0.0546875000
 [4,] 2.431559e-04 1.881950e-03 6.113802e-03 1.388160e-02 0.0258483887
 [5,] 2.430967e-05 3.756817e-04 1.822927e-03 5.475560e-03 0.0125901247
 [6,] 2.430908e-06 7.510810e-05 5.458812e-04 2.178231e-03 0.0062158067
 [7,] 2.430902e-07 1.502049e-05 1.636750e-04 8.693947e-04 0.0030885852
 [8,] 2.430902e-08 3.004053e-06 4.909445e-05 3.474555e-04 0.0015395229
 [9,] 2.430902e-09 6.008089e-07 1.472761e-05 1.389339e-04 0.0007685764
[10,] 2.430902e-10 1.201617e-07 4.418219e-06 5.556585e-05 0.0003839928
```

But when I use

```
plot(x, pch=20, ylim=c(0, 1))
```

I get the following: [Plot of R matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnMbr.png).

I want a plot, where `x[1, 1]` (i.e. `5.000000e-01`) is plotted as a point on 0.1 on the x-axis and 0.5 on the y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(123)
mat<-matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
colnames(mat)<-seq(0.1,0.5,length.out=5)
plot(x=matrix(rep(as.numeric(colnames(mat)),5), 5,5,byrow=T),y=mat)
```

here the first argument x will repeat the number on the x axis by 5, so 5 x 5 I'll get a matrix which will give the right x position to each y column.

```
matplot(x=matrix(rep(as.numeric(colnames(mat)),5), 5,5,byrow=T),y=mat)
```

Can also be used

Comment: And this is the error: `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ`

Comment: If you look at the result (graph that you get from it), you'll know that your answer is not working. Also use `set.seed()` to make your data reproducible.